# ¿Como realizar esta consulta SQL utilizando el ORM de django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

La consulta que quiero traducir es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM STOCK WHERE STOCK_MIN < STOCK;
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    stock=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    stock_min=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    producto=models.ForeignKey(MiProducto,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria así:

```
from django.db.models import F

Stock.objects.filter(stock_min__lt = F('stock'))
```

El [`lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#lt) o [`__lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#lt) es menos que (`<`), hay `gt`, `gte`, `lt` y `lte`, para mas información revisa la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt).

Por otra parte las [**`F expressions`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

> Un objeto `F()` **representa el valor de un campo modelo o columna**
> anotada. Permite hacer referencia a los valores de campo del modelo y
> realizar operaciones de base de datos usándolos sin tener que sacarlos
> de la base de datos a la memoria de Python.

Entonces el `F('stock')` hace referencia al campo `stock` del modelo `Stock`.
Espero haberte ayudado.